# Set timeout length of my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I set the timeout length in my query ?

I'm generate script from my database, but it fails because of timeout length.

I tryied set on the Connect to Server window, pressing the Options button and there is an option for Execution time-out. That is 0.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you writing the query in Management Studio?

Comment: Setting the execution timeout to zero means that there is no execution timeout. It will wait foerever instead of doing a timeout. What are you executing, and how?

Comment: I'm gerenating script of a specific table in my DataBase. So, I go to task, generate script, and set to True the generate data script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to configure the Query Timeout period in SQL Management Studio do this:

```
> Open SQL Management Studio
> Click Tools > Options
> Expand Query Execution
> Expand SQL Server
> Select General
> Adjust Execution time-out
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Error: `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`

Comment: 707792 register in this table

Comment: Is your query accessing any remote SQL Server eg Select * from [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[Scheme].[TableName] ? If yes then you would also need to set the remote query timeout.